# In what specific order do I have to put the modules on the temporal communication system?

Tags: new-beginning-final-cut

Very early in the game you have to put together an Antenna to talk to your people in the  future. The cubic modules are supposed to make for one plane Area. I can't quite figure it out. So how exactly and in what order do you have to put the cubes on the antenna to solve this puzzle?

The antenna:

[image: Antenna]

The modules:

[image: modules]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objective is to form a 3x3 panel on each side of the antenna once you've finished arranging the cubes.

To achieve this, arrange the cubes as follows. On one side, place the following cubes from the case;

- bottom left
- top middle
- bottom middle

On the other side, place the remaining cubes as follows;

- top left
- top right
- bottom right

Once you've got them in the right order, a red light will start flashing on the antenna. Press the main switch on the antenna (red button/light) to activate and your antenna should look like this:

[image]

Here is a video on YouTube of the cubes being placed correctly;